# How to change $d^{log_2{n}}$ to be in the form $n^?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cannot find a property of logarithm to move n from the log in the exponent to the base. 
e.g $d^{log_2{n}}$ should be of the form $n^?$

Thanks!

Comment: Try calculating what $\log_2(d^{\log_2 n})$ is, and see where you can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$d=2^{\log_2(d)} \implies d^{\log_2(n)}= 2^{\log_2(d)\log_2(n)}=2^{\log_2(n)\log_2(d)}=n^{\log_2(d)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just write $d^{\log_2(n)} = n^{\alpha}$, take logarithms and see what happens by using properties of the logarithms

Answer (score 0):

$$d^{\log_2 n}=e^{(\log_2 n) \log d}=e^{(\log n)\left(\frac{\log d}{\log 2}\right)}=n^{log_2 d}$$

Comment: If using MathJax is too much trouble, just don't post.